# how to change the content-transfer encoding to 8 bit mime in swiftmailer?

Tags: yii2, phpmailer, swiftmailer

For avoiding the spam message the following was the instruction got from zoho

```
Until then please change the content-transfer encoding so as to avoid 8 bit mime to prevent DKIM signatures from failing.
```

How can change content-transfer encoding  with the Swiftmailer or yii2 mailer ?

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly you want to avoid 8-bit encoding and not to set it?

You can set encoder for the SwiftMailer message like:

```
$message->setEncoder(
    new \Swift_Mime_ContentEncoder_PlainContentEncoder('7bit')
);
```

I'm not sure how to do this with Yii 2 extension. You can try something like:

```
$message = Yii::$app->mailer->compose()
    ->setFrom('...')
    ->setTo('...')
    ->setSubject('...');

$message->getSwiftMessage()->setEncoder(
    new \Swift_Mime_ContentEncoder_PlainContentEncoder('7bit')
);

$message->send();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this instead of the plain content encoder

```
$message->setEncoder(Swift_Encoding::get8BitEncoding());
```

Comment: Note: as of SwiftMailer ^6.0, the class Swift_Encoding has been removed [source](https://github.com/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/blob/6484964bfa7ce98cb3683726963e4dee0ac62aac/CHANGES#L82)